# How to calculate eigen values and evectors of Jordan Block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

If there is a Jordan block matrix with $A(i,i) = a$ for all $i=1$ to $n$, $A(i,i+1)=b$ for all $i=1$ to $n-1$ and $A(j,k)=0$ otherwise. What will be eigenvalue and eigenvector of $J$?

To calculate eigenvalues I split the matrix in a diagonal matrix $= diag(a)$ and another matrix $B$ with $A(i,i+1)=b$. As $B$ is singular matrix, one of the eigenvalues will be zero. So for Jordan block matrix eigenvalue become $=a+0 =a$. How to find rest of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: what you have described is an upper triangular matrix, hence the only eighenvalue is a

Answer (score 2):

Note that there is only one eigenvalue in this case: that's $a$.

To find the eigenvectors, solve the linear system
$$
AX=aX\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad (A-aI_n)X=0.
$$
If $b\neq 0$, the solutions are easily seen to be
$$
\mbox{span}(1,0,\ldots,0).
$$
These are the eigenvectors.

If $b=0$, you the solutions/eigenvectors are obviously the whole vector space since $A-aI_n=0$.